# Flask giving an internal server error instead of rendering 404

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, flask

In my Flask app, I set up a 404 handler like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

However, when a user goes to an unrecognized URL, the system gives an internal server error instead of rendering my `404` template.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you create the template `404.html`?  Either way, post the stack trace for your error.  Enable debug mode or logging for your app, or just check the console if you're using the built-in development server.

Comment: My error page didn't work until I returned a string like 'error 404'. Then, I code 'render_template' and worked fine. I don't know the reason to make it work but you can try it.

Answer (score 8):

**Internal Server Error** is HTTP error 500 rather than 404 and you haven't added error handler for it. This occurs when the server is unable to fulfill the client request properly. To add a gracious message when such error occurred, you can add a *errorhandler* like 404.

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def exception_handler(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

Answer (score 1):

There is likely an issue while rendering the `404` template which then triggers an internal server error.

I suggest checking the logs for your app.

Answer (score 0):

This will also occur if you have debug set to true.  Try setting debug to false and see if your custom 404 shows up then.